# getting error for sudo apt-get upgrade?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, upgrade

when i enter `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following messages:

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree        
Reading> state information... Done 
Calculating upgrade... Done 
The following packages have been kept back:   
libavcodec54 libavdevice53 libavformat54 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

output for `sudo apt-cache rdepends libavcodec54`:

```
libavcodec54 Reverse Depends:   libavcodec54:i386   libavcodec54:i386 
libavcodec-extra-54:i386   libavcodec-extra-54:i386  |vlc-nox 
|libopenscenegraph99  |libavformat54  |libavfilter3  |libavdevice53  
libavcodec-extra-54   libavcodec-extra-54  |libavcodec-dev 
|libavcodec-dev  |libav-tools  |libav-dbg  |gstreamer1.0-libav 
|ffmpegthumbs  |audacity   libavcodec54:i386   libavcodec54:i386  
libavcodec-extra-54:i386   libavcodec-extra-54:i386  |xjadeo 
|transcode  |idjc  |zoneminder  |yorick-av  |xpra 
|xmms2-plugin-avcodec  |xbmc-bin  |vlc-nox  |tupi  |survex-aven 
|squeezelite-pa  |squeezelite  |spek  |silan  |shotdetect  |qutecom 
|python-renpy  |python-libavg  |performous  |paraview  |mpv  |mplayer2
|mplayer-gui  |mplayer  |mpd  |motion  |moc-ffmpeg-plugin  |miro 
|mencoder  |lynkeos.app  |lives  |lightspark-common  |libxine2-x 
|libxine2-ffmpeg  |libxine1-ffmpeg  |libwxsvg0  |libvxl1.17  |libvtk6 
|libvtk5.8  |libvisp2.8  |libquicktime2  |libqmmp-misc  |libphash0 
|libopenscenegraph99  |libopencv-highgui2.4  |libopal3.10.10 
|libmrpt-hwdrivers1.0  |libmrpt-dbg  |libmlt6  |libmediastreamer-base3
|libk3b6-extracodecs  |libjitsi-jni  |libgmerlin-avdec1  |libffms2-3 
|libffmpegthumbnailer4  |libchromaprint0  |libchromaprint-tools 
|libavifile-0.7c2  |libavformat54  |libavfilter3  |libavdevice53  
libavcodec-extra-54   libavcodec-extra-54  |libavcodec-dev 
|libavcodec-dev  |libavbin0  |libav-tools  |libav-dbg  |libaubio4 
|libasound2-plugins-extra  |kino  |kid3-core  |jmdlx  |hedgewars 
|harvid  |handbrake-cli  |handbrake  |guvcview  |gstreamer1.0-libav 
|gpac-modules-base  |goldendict  |gnash-common  |fuse-emulator-utils 
|forked-daapd  |ffmpegthumbs  |ffmpeg2theora  |ffdiaporama  |dvswitch 
|dvdstyler  |dvbcut  |dff  |cantata  |bombono-dvd  |blender  |bino 
|audacious-plugins  |aubio-tools  |amide  |acoustid-fingerprinter 
|ffmpegthumbs   libavcodec-extra-54:i386   libavcodec-extra-54:i386  
libavcodec54:i386   libavcodec54:i386  |libavfilter3  
libavcodec-extra-54   libavcodec-extra-54  |libavformat54 
|libavdevice53  |ffmpeg-dbg  |libavcodec-dev  |libavcodec-dev  |ffmpeg
|simplescreenrecorder
```

```
$ sudo apt-cache rdepends libavdevice53

libavdevice53 Reverse Depends:   libavdevice53:i386  
libavdevice53:i386   libopenscenegraph99   libavdevice-extra-53  
libavdevice-dev   libav-tools   libav-dbg   libavdevice53:i386  
libavdevice53:i386   libopenscenegraph99   libmlt6  
libavdevice-extra-53   libavdevice-dev   libav-tools   libav-dbg  
ffmpeg2theora   blender   bino   libavdevice53:i386  
libavdevice53:i386   libavdevice-extra-53   ffmpeg-dbg  
libavdevice-dev   ffmpeg
```

```
$ sudo apt-cache rdepends libavformat54

libavformat54 Reverse Depends:   libavformat54:i386  
libavformat54:i386   vlc-nox   nepomuk-core-ffmpegextractor  
libopenscenegraph99   libkfilemetadata4   libavformat-extra-54  
libavformat-dev   libavfilter3   libavdevice53   libav-tools  
libav-dbg   gstreamer1.0-libav   ffmpegthumbs   audacity  
libavformat54:i386   libavformat54:i386   xjadeo   transcode   idjc  
zoneminder   yorick-av   xbmc-bin   vlc-nox   tupi   survex-aven  
squeezelite-pa   squeezelite   spek   silan   shotdetect  
python-renpy   python-libavg   performous   paraview  
nepomuk-core-ffmpegextractor   mpv   mplayer2   mplayer-gui   mplayer 
mpd   motion   moc-ffmpeg-plugin   miro   mencoder   mediatomb-common 
lynkeos.app   lives   lightspark-common   libwxsvg0   libvxl1.17  
libvtk6   libvtk5.8   libvisp2.8   libqmmp-misc   libphash0  
libopenscenegraph99   libopencv-highgui2.4   libmrpt-hwdrivers1.0  
libmrpt-dbg   libmlt6   libkfilemetadata4   libk3b6-extracodecs  
libjitsi-jni   libgmerlin-avdec1   libffms2-3   libffmpegthumbnailer4 
libdlna0   libchromaprint-tools   libavifile-0.7c2  
libavformat-extra-54   libavformat-dev   libavfilter3   libavdevice53 
libavbin0   libav-tools   libav-dbg   libaubio4   kradio4   kino  
kid3-core   hedgewars   harvid   handbrake-cli   handbrake  
gstreamer1.0-libav   gpac-modules-base   goldendict   gnash-common  
gmerlin-encoders-ffmpeg   fuse-emulator-utils   forked-daapd  
ffmpegthumbs   ffmpeg2theora   ffdiaporama   dvdstyler   dvbcut   dff 
cmus-plugin-ffmpeg   cantata   bombono-dvd   blender   bino  
audacious-plugins   aubio-tools   acoustid-fingerprinter  
libkfilemetadata4   ffmpegthumbs   libavformat54:i386  
libavformat54:i386   libavfilter3   libavformat-extra-54  
libavdevice53   ffmpeg-dbg   libavformat-dev   ffmpeg  
simplescreenrecorder
```

```
$ sudo apt-get install libavcodec54 libavdevice53 libavformat54

Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libavdevice53 :
Depends: libavcodec54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to
be installed or
                          libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libavfilter3 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed  libavformat54 : Depends: libavcodec54 (>=
7:1.2.5~) but 6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed or
                          libavcodec-extra-54 (>= 7:1.2.5~) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
broken packages.
```

I am using linux mint 17.1 cinnamon.

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` But please read into it before executing See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it I found the answer by searching for "The following packages have been kept back"

Comment: If you meant `dist-upgrade` jmunsch is correct.  If you meant `upgrade` see my answer.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-get intall libavcodec54 libavdevice53 libavformat54`? Please paste into the question.

Comment: please look  !!!

Comment: What does `apt-get --simulate dist-upgrade` say? Does it want to install or remove any packages?

Answer (score 1):

We need to see what package depends on those packages.  To do so, issue:

```
sudo apt-cache rdepends libavcodec54
sudo apt-cache rdepends libavdevice53
sudo apt-cache rdepends libavformat54
```

My hunch is vlc.  If that is the case, issue:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc
```

then try upgrading then reinstall vlc

Comment: nope still  problem exits !!!

Comment: should i provide output for :-  1) sudo apt-cache rdepends libavcodec54
2) sudo apt-cache rdepends libavdevice53
3)sudo apt-cache rdepends libavformat54

Comment: Yes provide output in your Original Post.

Comment: updated  please look !!

Comment: After reading that list and seeing [Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade), I think you better do a `dist-upgrade`.